# Return string when catching HttpRequestValidationException in [WebMethod]

Tags: .net, web-services, try-catch, asmx, webmethod

So, I'm trying to hide the error for HttpRequestValidationException.

This is my WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod]
public string ToLower(string inputString)
{
    try
    {
        return inputString.ToLower();
    }
    catch (HttpRequestValidationException)
    {
        return "[INVALID]";           
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return String.Format("Something went wrong-> {0}", ex);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why it doesn't return "[INVALID]" when it catches HttpRequestValidationException? 
Also what would be the best way to avoid showing errors like this:

System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (inputString="<!doctype html> <htm...").
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString(String value, String collectionKey, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__3(String key, String value)
   at System.Web.HttpValueCollection.EnsureKeyValidated(String key)
   at System.Web.HttpValueCollection.Get(String name)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ValueCollectionParameterReader.Read(NameValueCollection collection)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HtmlFormParameterReader.Read(HttpRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: The best way to avoid that error would be for the client to stop sending HTML to a SOAP Web Service. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I must find a way to fix this from the webservice, it's homework. Also ASMX is still in the MTA 98-361 exam certification. Thanks

Comment: You cannot fix it from the web service, it has to do with the client and the ASP.NET infrastructure. And thank you for making a great point on the value of certifications.

Comment: @JohnSaunders but with WCF is it possible?

Comment: I think you need to specify why you are sending HTML to your service. Most things are possible to WCF, but some make no sense.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I'm sending HTML because I want to get an exception, than to find a way to not show that error, just to get and friendly return or something. For example, I don't want a user to see the error if something unexpected occurs, but I must fix this only from the WS in try catch

Comment: Very strange course. Definitely not a real-world requirement, BTW.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Ok, here is a scenario. You have a Database Server, a Web Service server, a ASP.NET server, a user that make a request. Something occurs in the database , and the user gets an error, you have access only to the webservice code, how can I fix this with try/catch?

Comment: That's a totally different scenario. The answer is "catch the exception at the top level of the service, and return an appropriate fault". The service is not responsible for friendly error messages. The presenatation layer (ASP.NET) is responsible for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68743/discussion-between-stefan-and-john-saunders).